# Update props from other component in react native

Tags: react-native, components, react-props

I have a Main class which I show an array to user, then in detail page user can edit each element which I'm passing using react navigation parameter. I want to edit my array in the detail class and save it using async storage.

```
//Main.jsimport React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet ,
     Text,
     View, 
     TextInput,
     ScrollView,
     TouchableOpacity,
     KeyboardAvoidingView,
     AsyncStorage
    } from 'react-native'
import Note from './Note'
import detail from './Details'
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";


export default class Main extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'To do list',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
  };

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      noteArray: [],
      noteText: '',
      dueDate: ''
    };
  }

  async saveUserTasks(value) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:userTask',JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error saving data" + error);
    }
  }
   getUserTasks = async() =>{
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:userTask');
      if (value !== null){
        this.setState({ noteArray: JSON.parse(value)});
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
    }
  }

render() {
  this.getUserTasks()
    let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val,key) => {
      return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
      deleteMethod={ () => this.deleteNote(key)}
      goToDetailPage= {() => this.goToNoteDetail(key)}
       />
    });
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return(
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.keyboard}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                {notes}
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.footer}>
                <TextInput
                onChangeText={(noteText) => this.setState({noteText})}
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder='What is your next Task?'
                placeholderTextColor='white'
                underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
                >
                </TextInput>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addNote.bind(this)} style={styles.addButton}>
                <Text style={styles.addButtonText}> + </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
   </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      );
    }
    addNote(){
      if (this.state.noteText){
        var d = new Date();
        this.state.noteArray.push({ 
        'creationDate': d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDay(), 'taskName': this.state.noteText,'dueDate':'YYYY/MM/DD'
        });
        this.setState({noteArray:this.state.noteArray})
        this.setState({noteText: ''});
        this.saveUserTasks(this.state.noteArray) 
      }
    }
    deleteNote(key){
      this.state.noteArray.splice(key,1);
      this.setState({noteArray: this.state.noteArray})
      this.saveUserTasks(this.state.noteArray)       
    }
    goToNoteDetail=(key)=>{   
      this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen', {
        selectedTask: this.state.noteArray[key],
      });
    }     
}
```

in detail view I have this method which is similar to add note in main class:

```
export default class Details extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const selectedTask = navigation.getParam('selectedTask', 'task');
    return(
     <View key={this.props.keyval} style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.saveEdit.bind(this)} style={styles.saveButton}>
                <Text style={styles.saveButtonText}> save </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
  }
  saveEdit(){

    let selectedItem = { 'creationDate': selectedTask['creationDate'], 
    'taskName': selectedTask['taskName'],
    'dueDate': this.state.dueData}


this.props.navigation.state.params.saveEdit(selectedItem)
      }
    }
```

How can I change my props in any component?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't call this.getUserTasks() in the render method because the function has this.setState which is bad and could end in a endless loop I guess or at least effect in worse performance. You could instead call it in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getUserTasks();
}
```

Or alternatively call already in constructor but I prefer the first option:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    noteArray: [],
    noteText: '',
    dueDate: ''
  };

  this.getUserTasks()
}
```

this.props.noteArray.push({.. is probably undefined because you aren't passing it down any where. (Didn't see any reference in your snippet). I guess I would implement the saveEdit function in the Main.js component and simply pass it down to the navigation route and call the function in Details component by accessing the navigation state props:

**Update**

```
  goToNoteDetail=(key)=>{   
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen', {
      // selectedTask: this.state.noteArray[key],
      selectedItem: key,
      saveEdit: this.saveEdit
    });
  }     

  saveEdit(selectedItem){
    const selectedTask = this.state.noteArray[selectedItem]
    this.state.noteArray.push({ 
      'creationDate': selectedTask['creationDate'], 
      'taskName': selectedTask['taskName'],
      'dueDate': this.state.dueData
    });
    this.setState({noteArray:this.state.noteArray})
    this.setState({dueData: 'YYYY/MM/DD'});
    this.saveUserTasks(this.state.noteArray) 
  }
```

And then call saveEdit in Details Component:

```
saveSelectedItem = () => {
  const { navigation } = this.props.navigation;
  const {selectedItem, saveEdit} = navigation.state && navigation.state.params;
  saveEdit(selectedItem)
}
```

Comment: Then how should I implement the saveEdit method so I can pass '      'creationDate': selectedTask['creationDate'], 'taskName': selectedTask['taskName'],'dueDate':this.state.dueData' this from detail component

Comment: @Niloufar check my update. When you navigate to Details screen you set the key as selectedItem (you can also set it as "key" if you prefer). Then when you call saveEdit from Details component simply pass selectedItem as parameter to identify the current/selected task to update the task. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I still have error for this line   const {selectedItem, saveEdit} = navigation.state && navigation.state.params;
"undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigation.state')

Comment: Dear BigPun please check my update so you'll know if I have any mistake in my code, I'm new in react native and confused

Comment: I tried to go through your solution another time but now I get 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state')

Comment: @Niloufar can you please console.log(this.props.navigation) in Detail component and paste me the output

Comment: @Niloufar thats weird. Can you please send me the exact snippet where you console.log(this.props.navigation). Please copy paste the entire function :)