# Navigation.getParam is undefined while trying to pass function as parameter

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I'm trying to use a function from my Main component in my details component which I user react navigation to navigate to and I want to save some changes in detail screen in my main component

//Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet ,
     Text,
     View, 
     TextInput,
     ScrollView,
     TouchableOpacity,
     KeyboardAvoidingView,
     AsyncStorage
    } from 'react-native'
import Note from './Note'
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Details from './Details';


export default class Main extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'To do list',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
  };

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      noteArray: [],
      noteText: ''
    };
  }
render() {

    let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val,key) => {
      return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
      goToDetailPage= {() => this.goToNoteDetail(key)}
       />
    });
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
         <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                {notes}
            </ScrollView>
           <Details saveEdit={this.saveEdit} />
        </View>

      );
    }
    goToNoteDetail=(key)=>{   
      this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen', {
        selectedTask: this.state.noteArray[key],
        saveEdit: this.saveEdit
      });
    }
     saveEdit = (editedTask,dueDate) => {
     this.state.noteArray.push({ 
    'creationDate': editedTask['creationDate'], 
    'taskName': editedTask['taskName'],
    'dueDate': dueDate
  });
  this.setState({noteArray:this.state.noteArray})
  this.saveUserTasks(this.state.noteArray) 
}    
      this.setState({noteArray:this.state.noteArray})
      this.saveUserTasks(this.state.noteArray) 
    }     
}
```

Then I try to use it as prop in my Detail.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet ,
     Text,
     View, 
     TextInput,
     Button,
     TouchableOpacity,

    } from 'react-native'
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

export default class Details extends React.Component {

   constructor(props){
    super(props);
   this.state = {
    dueDate = ''
   }
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },  
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
  this.getUserTasks()  
  } 
  render() {

    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const selectedTask = navigation.getParam('selectedTask', 'task');
    var { saveEdit} = this.props;

    return(
     <View key={this.props.keyval} style={styles.container}>
      <View style = { styles.info}>
              <Text style= {styles.labelStyle}> Due date:
              </Text>
              <TextInput
                        onChangeText={(dueData) => this.setState({dueData})}
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        placeholder= {selectedTask['dueDate']}  
                        placeholderTextColor='gray'
                        underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
                        >
              </TextInput>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.saveEdit(selectedTask, this.state.dueDate)} style={styles.saveButton}>
                <Text style={styles.saveButtonText}> save </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I searched a lot to find the solution and I tried many of them but get different undefined errors. This is not what I did in the first place but when I search I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547751/react-native-pass-function-to-child-component-as-prop). And I know it causes lots of issues. 
 I want to know how can I manage to access to main method from details and pass parameters to it or how can I manage to use main props in my details component

Answer (score 6):

If you are using react-navigation 5, params is no longer under the navigation object but under route object. This is the link to the sample code:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
<Details saveEdit={this.saveEdit} />
```

to

```
<Details navigation={this.props.navigation} saveEdit={this.saveEdit} />
```

```js
render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
         <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                {notes}
            </ScrollView>
           <Details navigation={this.props.navigation} saveEdit={this.saveEdit} />
        </View>

      );
}
```

## Why?

You are using your `Details` component in `Main` screen. So you need to give `navigation` to `Details`'s props from your `Main` to use `navigation props` in `Details` component.

Because your `Details` component is not the screen component registered in your navigator(router).

Comment: Thanks, Sorry I didn't understand your question. I'm declaring my navigation using createStackNavigator in my App.js. Then I have to navigate to details and user will make changes to the selected item and I want to save it. I can do it by calling the save method from Main or by passing noteArray to details and save it there

Comment: And your solution causes me to have both component in one view, and it's not what I want!

Comment: I just answered how to solve your `Navigation.getParam is undefined`. Did you try it? Just change your render code in `Main` component to I recommended

Comment: Yes I did and it removed my error but it messed up my view. Please read my explanation. I want to save changes in my detail view. it's not necessary for me to pass method. either if I manage to use main props and states in detail it's enough

Comment: @Niloufar My code is not change your view. There is no code to change any layout. Your question is about how to solve `Navigation.getParam is undefined` error from your code. And that is all in this post.

Comment: When I used your solution, I saw my details view inside my main! and I dun;t understand why

Comment: @Niloufar Check your original code. You are already using your `Details` component in `Main`.

I think your navigation structure would be wrong. and it is totally another problem with this post.

Comment: I thinks it's better if I ask my question in another way:
I'm pushing to details view when user select edit button of each row, I want to show some details there and user can make changes. After pressing save I want to save those changes into my asyncStorage. I tried to use this.setState but I don't have access to noteArray in details. Then I tried to pass the edited object back to save it in main and I faced this issue.
Thanks for your time I know I'm new and dumb in react

Comment: Maybe you may see my other question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56396525/update-props-from-other-component-in-react-native/56396734?noredirect=1#comment99392501_56396734

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code on my machine but it seems you have too many syntax error in your code (maybe because of copy pasta?)

but it seems you should change

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.saveEdit(selectedTask, this.state.dueDate)}
```

in Detals.js to

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.navigation.getParams('saveEdit')(selectedTask, this.state.dueDate)}
```

for clarification this worked for  me
**in MainPage.js**

```
    _test(){
      console.log('test');
    }
.
.

.
<ActionButton
     buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)"
     onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate('AddNewSession', {test: this._test})}>
</ActionButton>
```

and in AddNewSession.js

```
  componentDidMount() 
    let test = this.props.navigation.getParam('test');
    test();
  }
```

Comment: Actually it's been three days that I've started coding in react native. as I paste my code here and removed unnecessary parts to be brief you get errors, I'm declaring my navigation using createStackNavigator in my App.js. Then I have to navigate to details and user will make changes to the selected item and I want to save it. I can do it by calling the save method from Main or by passing noteArray to details and save it there. Do have any solution for me?

Comment: It seems like a very straightforward problem, I suggest do all your changes ad edits inside Detail.js that way you don't need to pass functions around. Although as I said in my answer i think you only need to change this.props.saveEdit, rest of code seems okayish

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes within your codes. First of all you are importing the navigation build-in function {createStackNavigator} in all your files, Main.js and Details.js :

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from
"react-navigation";
```

That make me think that you didn't know how the stack navigation or navigation in general functions in react native. You should have a file that handles your routes configuration, let call it MyNavigation.js and then define the routes 'Main' and 'details' in MyNavigations,js. It's only inside MyNavigation.js that you can import "createStackNavigator". Then you will define your functions to move between the screens "Main" and "detail". Those functions will be passed as props to the routes when moving between one another. The overall action wihtin MyNavigation.js will look like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Main from './Main';
import Detail from './Detail';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function goToDetailFromMainScreen(){
     return(this.props.navigation.navigate('switch2'));
      }
function DetailSaves(){
     return(//your code here to save details);
      }

 //Here you pass the functions to Main Component to handele Detail componets 
   's actions

function switch1(){
  return(<Main GoToDetails={() => this.goTodetailFromMainScreen()} paramsForDetailActions={() => this.detailSaves()} />)
}

function switch2(){
  return(<Details />)
}

export default function MyNavigation() {
  return(
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='switch1'>
       <Stack.Screen name='switch1' options={{header:()=>null}} component={Main} />
       <Stack.Screen name='switch2' options={{headerTitle:"Detail"}} component={Detail} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
)
}
```

Now inside Main.js you check the props functions passed to it from MyNavigation.js:

// Main.js

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  goToDetails = () => {
    this.props.onPress?.();
  }
   paramsForDetailActions= () => {
    this.props.onPress?.();
  }
```